# How to run uiautomatorviewer in java 11?

Tags: uiautomatorviewer

C:\Users\Shruti>uiautomatorviewer
-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.14\lib;..\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

First I had java 15 but I heard java 8 is compatible for uiautomatorviewer but it didn't helped then I uprgaded it to java 11 but same issue plz help

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't make it work with Java 11 and I doubt it's possible to as there may be substantial differences in the APIs used, but I was able to run it using Java 8 while maintaining Java 11 as the default java.
Simply open `<android-sdk>/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer` with a text editor and replace

```
javaCmd="java"
```

with

```
javaCmd="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java"
```

(or whatever your path to java 8 bin is located)